# create a new column based on ifelse / case_when condition of first occurrence

Tags: r

My data looks as follows:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 2
   positives negatives
       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1         1         0
 2         1         0
 3         0        -1
 4         0         0
 5         0         0
 6         1         0
 7         0         0
 8         0         0
 9         0        -1
10         0        -1
# ... with 90 more rows
```

I want to create two new columns where the data will eventually look like:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 2
   positives negatives    newcol1     newcol2

 1         1         0       1           0
 2         1         0       0           0
 3         0        -1       0          -1
 4         0         0       0           0
 5         0         0       0           0
 6         1         0       1           0
 7         0         0       0           0
 8         0         0       0           0 
 9         0        -1       0          -1
10         0        -1       0           0
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Where `newcol1` takes the first occurrence of the `1` in the `positives` column - all subsequent rows in this column will be `0` until there is a `-1` in the `negatives` column. Then the `newcol2` column will take on a `-1` until there is a "new - first" occurrence of a `1` in the `positives` column.

Another example using the bottom 20 rows:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   positives negatives    newcol1      newcol2
       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1         0        -1       0            -1
 2         0         0       0             0
 3         0        -1       0             0  # a 0 since we have not had a 1 in "positives"
 4         1         0       1             0  # now we have a 1 so put a 1 in newcol1
 5         1         0       0             0  # 0 here since this is the 2nd occurrence of a 1 in this column
 6         0        -1       0             -1 # we add -1 here since its the first occurrence of a -1 in the negatives column after we encountered a 1 in the positives column
 7         0         0       0              0
 8         0         0       0              0 
 9         0         0       0              0 
10         1         0       1              0 # change back to the positives/newcol1 since this is the first 1 occurrence in the positives column after we encountered a -1 in the negatives column
11         1         0       0              0 # there was a 1 previously in the positives column so we ignore this 1 in the positives column (until we encounter a -1 in the negatives column)
12         0        -1       0             -1              
13         0        -1       0              0
14         0        -1       0              0
15         0         0       0              0 
16         0         0       0              0
17         0        -1       0              0 
18         0        -1       0              0
19         0         0       0              0 
20         0         0       0              0 # no other 1 in the positives column so we finish on a -1 in the newcol2 column.
```

Data:

```
structure(list(positives = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), negatives = c(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 
0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 
0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 
0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

Comment: This `df %>%
  mutate(newcol1 = replace(positives, positives == 1 & lag(positives) == 1, 0), 
         newcol2 = replace(negatives, negatives == -1 & lag(negatives) == -1, 0))` gives same answer as the accepted answer. But is this what you want ? Since I don't see any reference of `negatives` in `newcol1` column and same for `newcol2` for `positives`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `rleid` to create a grouping variable and then create the binary based on `all` values in 'positives' as 1 and the `row_number` is 1, and similarly with 'newcol2'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(grp = rleid(positives)) %>% 
    mutate(newcol1 = +(all(positives == 1) * row_number() == 1)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(negatives)) %>%
    mutate(newcol2 = -1 *(all(negatives == -1) * row_number() == 1)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 100 x 4
#   positives negatives newcol1 newcol2
#       <dbl>     <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>
# 1         1         0       1       0
# 2         1         0       0       0
# 3         0        -1       0      -1
# 4         0         0       0       0
# 5         0         0       0       0
# 6         1         0       1       0
# 7         0         0       0       0
# 8         0         0       0       0
# 9         0        -1       0      -1
#10         0        -1       0       0
# … with 90 more rows
```

---

Or as @H 1 mentioned, the `rleid` grouping can be applied once

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(grp = rleid(positives + negatives)) %>% 
    mutate(newcol1 = +(all(positives == 1) * row_number() == 1), 
           newcol2 = -1 *(all(negatives == -1) * row_number() == 1))
```